# Keyboard of javafx application on Android allows limited characters

Tags: android, keyboard, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I have a JavaFX application that runs on Android with the use of JavaFXPorts. When a textfield is edited the virtual keyboard (a.o. the widely used SwiftKey keyboard) does not allow typing all allowed characters. For example I was allowed to type "co" but then "c" was blocked, and even resulted in a submit. The backspace does not work either. Some Android keyboards to not have this behavior (so it is not a keyboard mode), neither does the application on desktop.

Comment: Some improvements were done regarding keyboard input in the following pull request: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/pull-requests/4/keymapping-improvements-done-by-stefan. This adds in support for dead keys for instance.
However, a custom implementation of the android input method system (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) is required to support more advanced IMEs, like swipe keyboards or keyboards for inputting CJK characters, etc.

Comment: Hmmm, I've taken a peek a the javafxports project and I'll try to run with the 1.0.8-SNAPSHOT. In that way I can also enable some of debug code I found scattered in that project to see where/why my keys are blocked.

Comment: I saw that 1.0.8 is out and quickly tested it, but with the focus in a textfield, pressing the "c" key still causes the ok button below the textfield to be pressed.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like, when a button is underneath the keyboard, that button still receives the touch events. It's that the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: What I'm seeing is that no matter which of the two textfields or one passwordfield the cursor is in, the keyboard is not fully responsive. Most notably the backspace key. And pressing the c key clicks the button, but the t key actually adds a t to the textfield. So you can add t's, not remove them and c makes it execute the login action. The form works perfectly on PC and the iOS emulator.

Comment: Had time to work on it some; it is related to the SwiftKey keyboard. If I select the Xperia keyboard (testing on a Sony Z5 compact), then there is no problem.